# prepareForSegue won't work with custom segue (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I've created a custom segue and it keeps giving the same error. It happened even when I've created a real simple UIStoryboardSegue Class.

> Overriding method with selector 'prepareForSegue:sender:' has
>   incompatible type '(CustomOpenSegue, AnyObject?) -> ()'

This is how I'm calling it

> ```
> override func prepareForSegue(segue: CustomOpenSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
>
>     segue.iconFrame = sender!.view!.frame
>
> }
> ```

My custom segue will work without the prepareForSegue (on a simpler mode) but I need to pass iconFrame a value for it to work as intended.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue is CustomOpenSegue {
        let customOpenSegue = segue as! CustomOpenSegue
        customOpenSegue.iconFrame = sender!.view!.frame
    }
}
```

If you override a method, you can't change the parameter types.

Comment: It won't work because UIStoryboardSegue doesn't have a member named iconFrame, which exists in my custom segue class. Any suggestion?

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add a type check and a cast.